# Adding help text to a form field using Jquery

Tags: joomla-3.3.x, jquery

I am trying to add help text to a form field. When the user clicks in the field, corresponding help text will be shown  just below the field. As i have said before i am newbie when it comes to jquery. The jquery code that i have added to my form is as shown.

```
$("#username").focus(function() {
  $(".name-help").slideDown(500);
}).blur(function() {
  $(".name-help").slideUp(500);
});
```

$(".email").focus(function() {
  $(".email-help").slideDown(500);
}).blur(function() {
  $(".email-help").slideUp(500);
});
The problem is i am not sure if that's the correct way of embedding jquery functions in php + html code. This is not working. When i inspect the page i get the following errors

**1. $ is not a function agent-register**

**2. Empty string passed to getElementById()**

Can anyone help me to fix this? What i am doing wrong here? Or is there an alternative way to achieve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Which file are you currently adding your code in?

Comment: Do i add the code snippet or something? But you can check out the form here [here](http://cheaphouses.co.ke/agent-register)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You're using `$(".email")` but there is only an ID assigned to this input field, not a class, so you need to replace it with `$("#email")`.
2. You need to wrap you code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function($){ ... });`

I've altered your code for you:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#username').focus(function() {
        $('.name-help').slideDown(500);
    }).blur(function() {
        $('.name-help').slideUp(500);
    });

    $('#email').focus(function() {
        $('.email-help').slideDown(500);
    }).blur(function() {
        $('.email-help').slideUp(500);
    });

});
```

And also provided you with a live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7jrzxgu/

Hope this helps

Comment: This has helped! It is now working. The only problem is i am getting numerous jquery errors titled **Empty string passed to getElementById()** But thank alot

Comment: `getElementById()` had nothing to do with the code in your question. This is coming from somewhere else ;) Glad the answer helped though :)